# How to block facebook

Tags: networking, iptables, facebook, whois

I want to try blocking facebook on my machine.

I started using /etc/hosts but that doesn't catch all subdomains, so I did some research and found [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/blocking-facebook-web-trackers-at-the-firewall-for-extra-privacy) (and many similar solutions) which lead to this statement

```
/usr/bin/whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934' | head -n -1 | tail -n -1 | /usr/bin/xargs --max-args=1 | /usr/bin/xargs -I {} --max-args=1 iptables -A OUTPUT -d {} -j REJECT
```

[edit]
what I do here is, that I first use

```
whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934'
```

to get all ip-ranges, registered by facebook, like suggested by [this artice](https://www.howtoforge.com/blocking-facebook-web-trackers-at-the-firewall-for-extra-privacy). Then I do some trimming, to remove unwanted chars at the beginning and end of the result. This gives me a list of ip-ranges, seperated by spaces. Using xarg, I then seperate these ip-ranges and build, for each ip-range, a statement like

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d {} -j REJECT
```

where `{}` is replaced by the actual range. I use `REJECT`, not `DROP` since 1. it is a lot faster 2. since I actually want to forbid the connection, this seems right to me.
[/edit]

now if I try `ping facebook.com` I get

```
From myname (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
```

which is exactly what I expect. But if I use my browser (Firefox) to open facebook.com the site still opens, which is not what I expect. I tried reloading and opening another facebook domain (facebook.de) which I haven't tried before to rule out problems with the browser cache, but that didn't help.

Since I often see `DROP` instead of `REJECT` I tried that too, but it didn't change the outcome.

The question now is, why can the browser load a webpage, if the corresponding ip is blocked? How can the browser get through, if the ping is blocked? It is obvious, that I am missing something, but I can't figure out, what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Get host ip:

```
host -t a facebook.com
```

Find CIDR

```
whois 173.252.120.68 | grep CIDR
```

And block subnet

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 173.252.120.68/18 -j DROP
```

and block domains:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d www.fаcebook.com -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d fаcebook.com -j DROP
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help.  With `whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934'` I already get a wide range of IP-Adresses, registered to facebook, including `173.252.96.0/19` so `173.252.120.68/18` should already be covered.  I tried your suggestion of also blocking `facebook.com` and `www.facebook.com` by name, but that didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: make easier, to add string in /etc/hosts  `127.0.1.1      facebook.com www.facebook.com` it will be work only your machine.

Comment: facebook uses a lot of subdomains like `staticxx.facebook.com` which I want to block too, but I don't know them all. Also, I want to block not only `facebook.com` but all facebook domains, like `facebook.de`, `facebook.fr`, `facebook.uk`, etc. Thus I can't use `/etc/hosts`, since it doesn't support wildcards.  That is why I use `whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934'` to get all of Facebooks registered IP-ranges.

Comment: you can get the up to date ip tables and instructions here: https://github.com/Ra-Na/blockfacebook